# Is it safe/correct to return a string from a function that had its memory allocated on the same function?

Tags: c

I understand that if I want to return a string literal or an array from a function I should declare it as static so the contents don't "die" when the called function is returned.

But my question is, what about when I allocate memory using malloc inside a function?

In the following function:

```
char * getLine() {

    char *line = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(line, 10, stdin);

    return line;
}
```

The memory address returned from this function is still safe even after the function getLine returns?

Comment: `malloc`ed memory remains valid until it is `free`d, so yes, that's okay. (Except that you don't check the return value of `malloc`.)

Comment: Yes, but the caller now has the responsibility of deallocating the string when it is no longer used.

Comment: yes. `malloc` allocates on the heap. It's only the stack's memory which is lost after the function returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that if I want to return a string literal or an array from a function I should declare it as `static`

That's not exactly right: although declaring it `static` would fix the problem, so would allocating it in the dynamic memory, i.e. `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`/`strdup`/etc. So the answer is "yes, returning `malloc`-ed memory from a function is perfectly safe". Of course the caller that receives dynamic memory must take care of `free`-ing it when it is no longer needed.

**EDIT :** (in response to comments) In fact, using `static` may be inferior in some contexts, because the buffer would remain shared. For example, if you decide to make a list of user-entered strings, you would be forced to make copies in the caller. In addition, using `static` would make your function non-reentrant, which is harmful in concurrent environments.

Comment: @ItaloGrossi Yes, that would be exactly how you wrote it in your post.

Comment: I know I should not post this here but I have to say.
I've started using this website (for real) a few days ago and it's brilliant! I learn more in here than I ever did with any professor! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Declaring it static might or might not "fix the problem". Returning a pointer to static memory has its own pitfalls -- a second call to `getline()` would overwrite the contents of the first, which might not be the expected result.

Comment: I'd even like to add that declaring a buffer as "static" brings you actually into hot water under some circumstances. Especially if you have multiple subsequent, independend calls. So try to avoid function local static variables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but then something else has to call `free` on the same pointer, or the memory will remain allocated until the process exits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really clarified this to me.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, returning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory is fine.

But, as also has been stated, the caller now has to keep track of when that memory is no longer needed and deallocate it.

In cases like this one, it is often wiser to let the caller supply the memory to be filled since this solves the problem with ownership of memory and it adds the benefit of being able to fill any (pre)allocated chunk of memory with data.

So, your function might look like this:

```
char* get_line(char* dst, int size) {
  printf("Enter a string: ");
  fgets(dst, size, stdin);

  return dst;
}
```

Now you can call this function in a loop or whatever matches your needs and the function itself only has two side effects (apart from writing to memory): writing to the terminal and reading from it. This is good.